# using an llvm backend (Mips, Sparc etc)

Tags: llvm

I am trying to find some code examples which allow me to hook up a llvm backend for code generation. For example, hooking up the IR to either the Mips or Sparc backend. However, I haven't been able to find any such examples. The only closest thing I could find is the use of the AMD IL & GPU backend, currently in the mesa tree but not yet merged into the llvm backend. I have read the Writing an LLVM Backend tutorial but its not really obvious to me as to how to   hook up the backend. I am sure I am missing something from the examples so could someone point me to some examples for this ? I already have code to generate the IR.
Thanks

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67/pic32_samples I have some mips examples that use both gcc and llvm/clang as cross compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the LLVM llc command. It reads a bitcode IR file and calls any of the backends on it.

Comment: Thanks so much. That does give some idea.

Answer (score 1):

The llc command would compile LLVM IR to target machine assembly.
With argument "march=[your target]", you can get assembly for different targets, 
"march=mips" for Mips, for example.